# Rescue usb for ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb

I have 22.04 installed (uefi GPT). I want to create a bootable USB from which I can run, say, fsck on the unmounted system. I set up my USB using Rufus and ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso. I did this following https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview. When this boots it appears to want to install ubuntu. I don't want it to do that unless it is going to install on the USB! The last thing I want is for it to install over my existing system. How can I be sure it won't do that? Sorry if this is a dumb question but I don't want to risk ruining my present setup which I am very pleased with.

Answer (score 0):

To reach a live shell in the Ubuntu Server image,

- First, enter the installer (you are not yet committing to an install).
- Then, look for the "Help" menu in the upper right corner.
- The option to open a Live shell environment is in that Help menu.

or

- First, enter the installer (you are not yet committing to an install).
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or F3 or F4 or F5 or F6) to reach a shell.

Comment: Both of these options are accurate thanks. Perhaps the label 'help' could be altered to something like 'other options'